# Remove the "login part" in the startup stage [unlocking the disk]

Tags: startup

I want to remove the "login part" in the startup stage.
It is too disturbing.
It's showed that "unlocking the disk/dev/disk/by-uuid/2e97702d-a4db-4d1b-8b0c-d3714dbde728(sdas_crypt) Enter pass pharase"

Maybe my problem is come from "For more security : tick" on the intallation process of ubuntu.
I don't want to reinstall ubuntu. 
How can I deal with that?

Comment: Maybe you are right. I can't undo the encryption...>< Oh~I don't want to reinstall. It must hurt my hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your system setting select user accounts and then unlock the administration account and then turn on automatic login.

Comment: The setting originally is "ON" .

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command:

`sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /apps/gdm/simple-greeter/disable_user_list true`

Comment: I don't know how to run this.
I am a newbie...

Comment: am sorry about that. just open the terminal(ctrl+t) type the command as it is. am also very new in this forum

Comment: I tried...but it still ask me for unlocking the disk.